# How to display 3 items in a row through looping with Asp.Net MVC Razor syntax

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

[image]
I came across a scenario where I want to display 3 items in a row. I was successful in displaying 2 items in a row. I tried, but could not display 3 items in a row. Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code snippet I tried

```
    @model  IList<MvcApplication1.tblTest>
   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Displaying three items(products) in a row</h2>

    <div style="display: inline-block">

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {

        <div style="display: inline-block">

            <div> @Model[i].testId</div>
            <div>@Model[i].testName</div>      
            <div>@Model[i].testDescription</div> 

        </div>   

        if (i% 3 == 1)
        {
        <br />
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Not seeing anything obviously wrong, Have you looked at the html returned to ensure it isn't there? May want to also output Model.Count() Just to be safe.

Comment: Hi Kelly thanks for the quick response. I attached the output screen shot. I am trying to display 3 items in a row but I was not able to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try i%3 ==2

```
@model  IList<MvcApplication1.tblTest>
   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Displaying three items(products) in a row</h2>

    <div style="display: inline-block">

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {

        <div style="display: inline-block">

            <div> @Model[i].testId</div>
            <div>@Model[i].testName</div>      
            <div>@Model[i].testDescription</div> 

        </div>   

        if (i% 3 == 2)
        {
        <br />
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Using <br> is not at a best option. This might solve your purpose but always try to avoid using break to show items in next line while using div. Try adding div with block in your condition.

Answer (score 3):

Surely adding a break is one way to do this,

but you can think of this approach to avoid adding `<br>` tags

Iterate list in two loops, one loop incrementing in steps of 3 till last element, other from 0 to 2. Add a div wrapper for every iteration of outer loop and for inner loop, values. This way you can get more structured HTML in your view.

```
//I have used bootstrap classed to style, you can have your own styling on this structure.

@model  IList<MvcApplication1.tblTest>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Displaying three items(products) in a row</h2>

<div style="display: inline-block">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 3)
    {
        <div class="row">
            @{
                int j = 0;
                for (; j <= 2 && i + j < Model.Count(); j++)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div> @Model[i + j].testId</div>
                        <div>@Model[i + j].testName</div>
                        <div>@Model[i + j].testDescription</div>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man! This helped a lot. This was exactly the algorithm that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

its really working.  thanks for that.

```
        @foreach (var item in WebApplication1.LanguageMang.AvailableLanguages)
        {
            <div style="display: inline-block"> <div>@Html.ActionLink(item.LanguageFullName, "ChangeLanguage", "Home", new { lang = item.LanguageCultureName }, new { @class = item.imgUrl })</div>
            </div>
        }

    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBkYh.png)